# Should [flipflop] tag be changed to [flip-flop]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The use of flip-flop is more common than flipflop. In addition, Oxford's dictionary redirects flipflop to flip-flop in both UK and US versions.

> *Definition of flip-flop in English:*
>
> **flip-flop**
>
> 1. ...
> 2. ...
> 3. *Electronics: A switching circuit which works by changing from one stable state to another, or through an unstable state back to its stable state, in response to a triggering pulse.*

The tag info, which is taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)), also says flip-flop.

> *a flip-flop or latch is a circuit that has two stable states and can be used to store state information.*

Flip-flop seems not only the common term, but also the correct one. So, should we change [[flipflop]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flipflop) tag to [flip-flop] or do some kind of redirection?

The tag is [[flip-flop]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flip-flop) on Stack Overflow, which is correct.

Comment: Only if we can change it back again next week

Comment: It seems no one had the idea to use a flip-flop tag yet

Comment: flip-flop requires extra typing if you don't know how to tab

Comment: @laptop2d This case is applicable to all tags that have dash (-). Flip-flop shouldn't be the only victim.

Comment: @ahmedus it was more of a observation, not a suggestion

Comment: @laptop2d OK, I got it.

Comment: @laptop2d but who really types out the entire tag? As soon as you start typing, you get a list of results, kinda like the Google search engine.

Comment: @KingDuken it was more of a observation, not a suggestion

Comment: Interesting to note that the user who says `flipflop` is easier to type in a comment on this question says `system-verilog` is more readable on this one: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7376/238188

Comment: I've raised this issue on Meta Stack Exchange. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362616/946172

Comment: @VoltageSpike I have mentioned you mentioned in this post on Meta Stack Exchange https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362616/946172

Comment: @ahmedus it's possible to fix tag spellings. See https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7411/238188

Comment: @shashank this post is three plus years old well before I was a moderator

Comment: @VoltageSpike your comment was on my deleted post on Systemverilog tag.

Answer (score 6):

`flipflop` is not very readable, and I think it should be changed to `flip-flop` for better readability *and* for correctness.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to change it. Anyone who types "fli" will be prompted with the suggested tag "flipflop" and will naturally select it.

Answer (score 3):

No matter which you end up preferring, flipflop and flip-flop should be tag aliases of each other, so that we don't end up with two separate ones.

That inherently solves the issue at hand without requiring *any* personal preference to prevail over the other. Very Solomonic, you can divide the child and eat it, or however the saying goes.

Comment: I have not heard of this barbaric saying, but it is very disturbing. Please remove it or use some other analogy instead (like eating a cake).

Comment: What is salomonic?

Comment: @ShashankVM this was an intentional mixup of two ideas: 1. the saying "can't eat a cake and have it", and the [story where "salomonic" comes from](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/split_the_baby#English). It is a joke! Obviously, nobody would eat a child, but the original story is actually about splitting a baby, sorry.

Comment: Phew! Glad to know it is a joke!

Comment: Note: It is not so simple to create a separate tag that is too similar to the older one, that is why we are also facing a problem with the `system-verilog` tag, or else I would have created `systemverilog` and `flip-flop` tags.