# Would a moderator remove the misspelled [operational-amplifer] tag from a locked post?

Tags: support, tag-cleanup

I noticed the other day that there is a [operational-amplifer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operational-amplifer) tag which has "amplifier" misspelled (it is missing an "i'). I've been slowly replacing it on the posts which use it with the correct [operational-amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operational-amplifier) tag, but there is one [locked post with the misspelled tag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/533333/51760) that I cannot edit. Would a moderator please fix the tag so the misspelled tag will be removed from the system?

Additionally, it might be a good idea to remove the "content dispute" lock on it since the user who asked the question no longer has an account on the site.

Comment: Wow, I had to read that several times to figure out what was misspelled. Nice catch.

Comment: @pipe I only noticed it because I was fixing the tags on a post that needed the [operational-amplifier] tag and noticed that the system was suggesting both the correct and misspelled tags as I started to type "operational".

Comment: The post was locked because someone kept vandalizing it

Comment: LOL I never noticed that missing 'i' till now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All done, exactly as you suggested. I've put the correctly-spelled tag on that question and deleted the wrongly-spelled tag (so I don't believe it exists any more).

Thanks for the tidy up.

Comment: Could see if you can help with fixing this tag spelling too? electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6266/238188